# MsalService properties undefined

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I've been trying to store some data from the MsalService but I keep getting the same error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined
```

I don't know why this error appears 'cuz I'm making a console log and those properties appear.

This is my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.msalBroadcastService.msalSubject$.pipe(
     filter((msg: EventMessage) => msg.eventType === EventType.LOGIN_SUCCESS),
   )
   .subscribe((result: EventMessage) => {
     this.setUser();
     console.log(result);
   });
}

setUser() {
    console.log(this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0].name, ' ',
    this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0].username, ' ',
    this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0].idToken)
    let profile: Profile;
    profile.FirstName = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0].name;
    profile.Email = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0].username;
    profile.Document = this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0].idToken;

    this.userService.profileUser = profile;
}
```

I'm trying to store this info inside userService so i don't have to make this calls inside every component that needs this info.

I really appreciate any kind of help :].

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are all asynchronous.  The console.log works, because you are subscribing to the msal subject.

Re-write your calls to getAllAcounts() to be async and you should get the results you're after.

```js
this.authService.instance.getAllAccounts().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((results) => {
  // do something
})
```